# Let A and B be sets of real numbers, where A is a proper subset of B. Prove that if B ∼ A then B is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

All I know for sure is that direct proof doesn't work, the contrapositive should though?

Comment: What's your definition of infinite?

Comment: What does tilde mean? Have equal cardinality?  If B is finite it has an element not in A.  If A has n elements, and there is a mapping from 1..n to A then there is an extended by bijection 1...n,n+1 where 1...n go to A and n+1 to the element.  So A not tilde B.

Comment: @fleablood the tilde mean that they have same cardinality. It is used to represent the "standard" equivalent relation between sets.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The contrapositive might be easier to show: if $X$ is finite, then $X$ is not equivalent to a proper subset. You can do this by induction on the number of elements of $X$.

Also, the fact that $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ and $f:B\to A$ is a bijection. Choose $x_1\in B\setminus A.$ Define $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ for $n=2,3,4,\dots.$ It is easy to see that the elements $x_n$ are distinct, i.e., the mapping $n\mapsto x_n$ is a bijection between the set $\mathbb N$ of all natural numbers and the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}\subseteq A\subset B.$ I'm not sure what definition of "infinite set" you're using, but this should be enough to prove that $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets.